# copy activity alternative in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

I have output from web activity in Azure data factory and I want to store the data in blob storage.
Is there any way other than Copy Activity and Function app that I can use to store data in blob storage?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can use following way to store data in blob storage.

Use `PUT` method to store web activity output to blob storage.

**Step1:** Use Web activity body as `@activity(‘Web1’).output`

[image]

Or  if you want to pass the "data" (depending on variable name) and not the headers use `@activity(‘Web1’).output.data`

[image]

**Step2:** For Authentication select Managed Identity and Resource should be  `https://storage.azure.com/`

[image]

For information follow this link - [Azure Data Factory Web activity save output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/129351/azure-data-factory-web-activity-save-output.html)